# datagridview image column export to excel

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I have a datagridview with several columns of text including a row with an image.

[Datagridview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxXYc.png)

When trying to export it the text without an image on using the following code i have no errors;

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Save to excel with headers
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'create object of excel
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
        Next
        For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
            .cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells("NHS Number").Value
            For j = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                .cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
            Next
        Next
    End With

    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    '
    ExcelSheet = Nothing
    ExcelBook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

When i include an image into the datagridview to export to excel i get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
```

Additional information: Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Any ideas?

Comment: The `Value` of a cell in a `DataGridViewImageColumn` is a `Byte` array, which I doubt can be written to Excel.  You'd likely have to convert it to some type that Excel understands.  If that is to be an `Image` then you can write your `Byte` array to a `MemoryStream` and then call `Image.FromStream`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney are you able to demonstrate an example? Sorry but I'm fairly new to visual studios and would greatly appreciate any help given!

Comment: You would definitely be able to find examples of that with a search.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney i have converted the image into a Byte but now i'm getting this problem when trying to add.row.data `(Additional information: Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <System.Drawing.Bitmap> in Image Column.  Expected type is Byte[].)`

Comment: It seems like you have converted the `Byte` array to a `Bitmap` and are now trying to display that `Bitmap` in the grid. I didn't tell you to do that. You asked how to export the data in the grid, which is a `Byte` array, to an Excel workbook. I said that you would probably need to convert that `Byte` FOR THAT EXPORT. I don't know what type you would need to convert it to - you can find that by research or by trial and error. I said that, if you are to convert it to an `Image` FOR THAT EXPORT then you can do so via a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Hey @jmcilhinney i have used the following code `Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Try
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
            Dim img As Byte()
            img = ms.ToArray()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(TextBox5.Text, img)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try

    End Sub`

Comment: How many times do I have to say the same thing? I'm not going to repeat myself again. Read my previous comments properly and do what they say. If you can read properly then I can't help you.